# Novel/Story with wireheads?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading a long time ago a novel where some people who, through a surgical operation had a wire connected to the pleasure center of their brains. They could just plug themselves in, it became an addiction. The were called wireheads. Does anyone recall what novel that was ?

Comment: Wireheads appear in several Larry Niven stories, but they are hardly a unique there. More detail would help.

Comment: Thanks, that could be it, is there any story in particular where they are introduced ? Sadly, I cannot remember any more details.

Comment: I believe it first showed up in Niven's [Death by Ecstasy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_by_Ecstasy). 
Abuse (for pleasure) of a brain implant meant for something else occurs in a slightly earlier novel [The Terminal Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminal_Man) by Michael Crichton. Incidentally, it also shows up in Spider Robinson's [Mindkiller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindkiller) and the related books in that series.  It's a pretty major plot element, although used in various ways.

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94578/novel-where-a-man-is-paid-to-travel-to-a-planet-inside-a-metallic-sphere/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per wikipedia:

> In Larry Niven's [Known Space](http://larryniven.wikia.com/wiki/Wirehead) stories, a wirehead is someone who has
> been fitted with an electronic brain implant (called a "droud" in the
> stories) to stimulate the pleasure centres of their brain. In the
> Known Space universe, wireheading is the most addictive habit known
> (Louis Wu is the only given example of a recovered addict), and
> wireheads usually die from neglecting themselves in favour of the
> ceaseless pleasure. Wireheading is so powerful and easy that it
> becomes an evolutionary pressure, selecting against that portion of
> Known Space humanity without self-control. Wireheading need not use an
> actual brain implant; the pleasure centre can be remotely activated by
> a small device called a "tasp" (important in the Ringworld novels)

"Wireheading" appears in several Niven works, notably [Flatlander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatlander_(short_story_collection)) and the [Ringworld Engineers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ringworld_Engineers)

> *She reminded me of a wirehead. You can't get a wirehead's attention, either, when house current is trickling down a fine wire from the top of his skull into the pleasure center of his brain. But no, the pure egocentric joy of a wirehead hardly matched Charlotte's egocentric misery.* <sub><sup>Flatlander - Larry Niven</sup></sub>

and

> *Times change. Generations later, these same cultures usually see
> current addiction as a mixed lessing. Older sins—alcoholism and drug
> addiction and compulsive gambling—cannot compete. People who can be
> hooked by drugs are happier with the wire. They take longer to die,
> and they tend not to have children.*
>
> *It costs almost nothing. An ecstasy peddler can raise the price of the
> operation, but for what? The user isn’t a wirehead until the wire has
> been embedded in the pleasure center of his brain. Then the peddler
> has no hold over him, for the user gets his kicks from house current.*
>
> *And the joy comes pure, with no overtones and no hangover.* <sub><sup>Ringworld Engineers - Larry Niven</sup></sub>

Comment: There's a line in John Steakley's  Armor about looking like "K Dick wireheads", which led me to believe it was a reference that went further back, to Philip K. Dick.  There's some speculation [here](http://www.network54.com/Forum/97413/thread/996361480/997113193/wireheads) to that effect.  I haven't read enough pkd to know myself, though.

Comment: A wirehead / wireheads appear in our own space and time in Spider Robinson's 1977 novella "God is an Iron" which was expanded into the 1979 novel  _Mindkiller_.

Comment: According to the linked Wikipedia article, (this) *Flatlander* is not a novel but a collection of stories including “Death by Ecstasy”.