# Star Trek Episode – Possible Time Travel or Alternative Timeline with No Federation

Tags: star-trek, movie, tv, episode-identification

In a *Star Trek* movie or TV episode, there is some sort of time travel or travel to an alternative timeline to Earth where they detect no Federation. But their sensors detect some Romulan ship activity at a distance (Possibly near Proxima Centauri).

Could anyone please point out which movie or season and episode is that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

"[Past Tense](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_Tense_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine))" - episodes 11/12 of DS9's third season.

> Back in the 24th century, the crew left on the Defiant, Major Kira,
> Odo, and Chief O'Brien, lose contact with Earth as all traces of the
> Federation suddenly vanish; Bell's death has radically altered the
> timeline.

From the [episode](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/457.htm):

> O'BRIEN: The only subspace signals I'm detecting are coming from the
> vicinity of Alpha Centauri. And they're Romulan.

Comment: Mostly set in a dystopian 2024, if you can imagine such a thing

Answer (score 3):

In Star Trek Strange New.Worlds S02E03 La'an Noonien Singh ends up being transported to an alternate Enterprise in a different timeline where there is no Federation. There is instead the United Earth Fleet. Spock is captain of a Vulcan ship named Sh'Rel and the Vulcans are fighting the Romulan Star Empire while humans are in a war with the Klingons. La'an and Captain James T. Kirk and up going back in time to stop a Romulan who is trying to kill Khan Noonien Singh so that the time line is altered and the Federation never comes into being.

Comment: The OP has already marked [Andrew's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/286091/122024) as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), as denoted by the green tick next to it, indicating that that is the correct answer.

Comment: @LogicDictates: A green tick does not indicate a correct answer, and never has.  It indicates that the poster of the question finds it the most helpful.  Posting another answer is a perfectly valid action, the OP may move the green tick to the new answer.

Comment: @Chenmunka - When it comes to story-ID questions, the standard practice is to only mark an answer as accepted if it's correct. And if a story-ID question has been correctly answered, it isn't valid to post additional answers that aren't correct.

Comment: On at least one occasion I posted a new answer after a previous answer had been accepted (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139610/alien-race-possibly-feline-takes-human-captive-en-route-to-final-battle-for-ea/278785#278785) - and I was right (the questioner accepted my new answer). In this case, however I think the new answer is not as good a match as the original - there is, for example, no scene in the present in which a character scans for a Federation signal and only finds Romulan signals  at Centauri.

Comment: @LogicDictates the thing with story ID is that some people think they are remembering the exact same story when they aren't. So while there is an accepted answer, posting a potential other possibility doesn't hurt anyone. It could help future searchers remember what _they_ were looking for, and even be the correct answer all along

Comment: The answer by @Andrew matches perfectly. I would like to thank Gordon for the effort, but there was no fighting with Romulan in that incident I explained. It was just about signals from their ship at alpha centauri..

Comment: @Andrew - If the OP of a story-ID question appears to have accepted an incorrect answer, then I agree that it's valid to post a new answer, but a scenario like that is the exception, not the rule, and this doesn't appear to be such instance.

Comment: @fez - When answering a question like this, I think the goal should always be to do so correctly. If an answer is likely to be incorrect, I don't think it should be posted, even if a wrong answer could be helpful to someone. My position on this is partly informed by the fact that there's a specific rule against the posting of questions seeking story recommendations. Such threads would likely be helpful to some users, but rightly or wrongly, they're not allowed, and that affects my attitude towards the posting of likely incorrect story-ID answers in general.

Comment: @LogicDictates mate all I’m saying is that just because there’s an accepted answer does not mean a new answer is any less valid. That’s why we don’t lock questions as soon as they have an accept, because sometimes the person doing the acceptance is wrong